# Cannot Get/ Error when running Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there are different variations of the same question, but I am getting a /Cannot Get error when running my node  server.

I assume is has something to do with these lines of code:

```
app.get('/:url', function (req, res) {
  wapp.init().then(function() {
    wapp.open(decodeURIComponent(req.params.url)).then(function(site) {
      site.analyze().then(function(results) {
        res.json(results)
```

Any advice on how I can fix this?

Context: This is an express application where when a user searches a domain on the front end, results specific to that URL are returned.

Comment: What happens if you remove everithing from whitin app.get('/:url', function (req, res) {}) still getting error?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Yea!

Comment: are you trying to load static fies

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Yup, loading static files, but the result returned depends on the user input